# How to fix the position of the text by resizing the font size according to the device screen size in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages

I have used a BottomAppBar widget and a floatingActionButton, In the picture some letters goes down which doesn't look nice.so instead is there a way to make those font size vary automatically depending on the screen size and remain in the same row?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply just wrap your Text widget to FittedBox widget like,

```
AppBar(
   centerTitle: true,
   title: FittedBox(fit:BoxFit.fitWidth, 
   child: Text('This is fitted box test')
  ),
),
```

Or you can use this lib
https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the following methods!

Use flutter AutoSizeText widget

https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text

```
AutoSizeText(
      "yourText",
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
),
```

You can use flutter FittedBox also:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html

```
AppBar(
    centerTitle: true,
    title: FittedBox(fit:BoxFit.fitWidth, 
    child: Text('Text which need to be resized')
           ),
),
```